# Combine @Published could not be found - Xcode11 Beta 5(11M382q)

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, ios13, combine

I am trying to run a simple project with the following:

`@Published var currentPlacemark: CLPlacemark? = nil`

- XCode11 Beta5(11M382q)
- iOS13(17A5556d)

Getting the following error:
`dyld: Symbol not found: _$s7Combine9PublishedV9PublisherCyx_GAadAM`

Anyone else encountered this?

Code example:

```
import SwiftUI
import Combine

class MyFoo {
  @Published var bar: String = ""
}

struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        Text("Hello World")
    }
}

#if DEBUG
struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        let foo = MyFoo()
      foo.bar = "asas"
        let barSink = foo.$bar
            .sink() {
                print("bar value: \($0)")
        }
        return ContentView()
    }
}
#endif
```

Comment: `Published` is defined in `Combine`. Can you try explicitly importing `Combine`?

Comment: Tried that, it didn’t work :(

Comment: Are you testing in a device? I think it is a bug. I see the same behaviour in my app, but it works in the simulator

Comment: @Tae Yap, testing on an iPhoneXS device with latest iOS13...

It seems that Apple did not match the Xcode version with latest iOS beta

Comment: Exactly. The latest iOS 13 beta is 7 while Xcode is stuck in beta 5

Comment: Still...
I would expect Apple to sync versions.

This is weird to say the least..

Opened a ticket on Apple Developer Forums.

Comment: Apple Developer Forums is not a “ticket”. If you find a bug you must file a bug through proper channels.

Comment: Having the same issue: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57513437/runtime-error-using-combine-dyld-symbol-not-found-s7combine9publishedv9publ

Comment: I just downloaded Xcode 11 beta 6 and it works with iOS 13 beta 7 

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a bug of the versions that you mentioned, I had the same issue. To solve it update to the new betas:

- Xcode 11 beta 6 (11M392q)
- iOS 13 beta 7 (17A5565b)

Comment: Yap..
The last update did the trick for me too.
Thank you @fdelafuente!