# Runtime error using Combine: dyld: Symbol not found: _$s7Combine9PublishedV9PublisherCyx_GAadAMc

Tags: swift, swiftui, combine

I'm using Xcode 11 Beta 5 (11M382q), and iphone x with iOS 13 beta 6 and I am having this runtime error when trying to use Combine:

> dyld: Symbol not found: _$s7Combine9PublishedV9PublisherCyx_GAadAMc

I have a Core class that is an `ObservableObject`

```
import SwiftUI
import Combine

open class Core: ObservableObject {
    @Published public var userId = ""

    public var isUserValid: AnyPublisher<Bool, Never> {
    return $userId.debounce(for: 0.5, scheduler: RunLoop.main).removeDuplicates().map { (user: String) in
      return user.isEmpty
    }.eraseToAnyPublisher()
  }
}
```

And a simple view

```
import SwiftUI
import Combine

struct LoginView: View {
    @EnvironmentObject var core: Core
    @State var isLoading: Bool = false
    @State var submitButtonEnabled: Bool = false

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            VStack(alignment: .center) {
                Image("logo")
                    .frame(minWidth: Constants.logoWidth, minHeight: Constants.logoHeight, alignment: .center)
                    .padding(.top, Constants.logoTopPadding)
                    .animation(.default)
                    .scaledToFit()
             }
        }

        CircularButton(isLoading: $isLoading, image: Constants.submitButtonArrowImageName) {
            // Button Action
        }
        .padding(.top, Constants.submitButtonTopPadding)
        .disabled($submitButtonEnabled.value)
        .onReceive(self.core.isUserValid) { value in
          self.submitButtonEnabled = value
        }
    }
}
```

What's wrong with my code? I Just want a MVVM architecture using reactive programming to disable or enable a button.

Comment: When you create an ObservableObject without @Published you have an ObservableObjectPublisher which is a publisher of <Void,Never>. If I read the definition of ObservableObject correctly then this is what the compiler does as well. That means that you are debouncing Void's. I believe that it would be easier to add a PassthroughSubject to Core and add .debounce() etc to the onReceive

Comment: But i'm debouncing on userId, which is <String, void>. Could you provide me an example of what you are proposing?

Comment: The publisher that is used for ObservableObjects is <Void,Never>, right click on ObservableObject in Xcode and you can see the definition, scroll down and you will see `Output = Void`. I have used OO's that have two publishers, one for SwiftUI and one for me: https://github.com/msalmonse/ColourViewer/blob/master/ColourViewer/Models/Observable.swift

Comment: Thanks, I'll take a look

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57481380/combine-published-could-not-be-found-xcode11-beta-511m382q

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I downloaded Xcode 11 beta 6, iOS 13 beta 7 and now is working fine. It was a bug from previous beta versions.