# Xcode 11 beta 5 / iOS 13 Public Beta 7 Combine crashes on device but runs in simulator

Tags: ios, xcode, swiftui

I am using the simulator to develop, but I wanted to deploy the app on my iPhone Xs, but I get the following exception:

dyld: Symbol not found: _$s7Combine9PublishedV9PublisherCyx_GAadAMc
  Referenced from: /var/containers/Bundle/Application/CBAC887B-8458-4C42-A74F-865FFF1BA7E3/yip.app/yip
  Expected in: /System/Library/Frameworks/Combine.framework/Combine
 in /var/containers/Bundle/Application/CBAC887B-8458-4C42-A74F-865FFF1BA7E3/yip.app/yip
(lldb)

I have Xcode 11 beta 5 and iOS 13 Public Beta 7 which should be compatible according to the developer site. And that was supposed to be the obvious mistake.

Do I need to take precautions before upgrading to a new version of Xcode?
Did anybody encounter this problem?

I used Xcode 11 beta 4 before that and it worked with my Phone.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57481380/combine-published-could-not-be-found-xcode11-beta-511m382q

Comment: Two things. First, there was a beta 7 release last Friday, hopefully that will help you out. Second, it didn't for me, but maybe something in this question - which is exactly the issue I'm facing - will spark something to help you. Finally? Let's hope that Apple releases a good Xcode beta 6 within 24 hours! https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57452325/after-upgrade-to-ios13-beta-6-xcode-11-beta-5-issue-dyld-symbol-not-found

Comment: You are right maybe I have updated to 7 already ...

Comment: I checked the build and it is indeed beta 7 sorry! I fixed the question